# Arithmetic mean vs. population mean

Tags: probability

Why is it that when you want to calculate the average of how much you scored in a group of exams you use the arithmetic mean formula and not the population mean formula?

When to use one and when to use the other?

EDIT: For example, I got Exam 1, Exam 2 and Exam 3. Exam 1 weighs 1, Exam 2 weighs 2 and Exam 3 weighs 3.

I score 50% on the first, 70% on the second and 90% on the third. In school, to calculate the average I would have to do:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nni*xi}{N}$$

ni being my score, xi being the weight and N being the total amount of exams.

My question is why is the arithmetic mean formula used in this case instead of the population mean, and when to use which.

Comment: I don't think you would.  Please give the details of why you think so.  If you just want the average of a group of exams you would use the arithmetic mean formula, maybe weighted if some count more than others.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @RossMillikan I edited it

Comment: You changed from thinking you would use population mean to using arithmetic mean.  You are not considering a sample of a population, you are considering the whole population (your test results).  The population mean corresponds to the arithmetic mean in this case.  I only know a special formula for the variance of the mean, where you divide by $n-1$ instead of $n$.  You don't do that to find the mean, just for the variance.  Is this what you are thinking of?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, I made a mistake. Before the edit when I said population mean I actually meant arithmetic mean. Sorry about that

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes that's what I am thinking. So, when I have a whole population I use the arithmetic mean and when I have only a sample I use the population mean?